# Could NOT find Qt6Quick (missing: Qt6Quick_DIR)

Tags: linux, qt, cmake, qtquick, qt6

Этот код работает:

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)
```

Этот не работает:

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets Quick)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
-- Could NOT find Qt6Quick (missing: Qt6Quick_DIR)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake

  but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Failed to find Qt component "Quick".

  Expected Config file at
  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6Quick/Qt6QuickConfig.cmake" does NOT
  exist
```

В системе установлены пакеты `qt6-base-dev`, `qt6-base-dev-tools` и `qt6-qmltooling-plugins`.
Может быть, какие-то ещё требуются?

Answer (score 0):

Установка `qt6-declarative-dev` решила проблему.

Также для кого-то, кто собирается пользоваться `Qt Quick`, полезным будет установить пакеты `qml6-module-qtqml`, `qml6-module-qtquick`, `qml6-module-qtquick-controls`, `qml6-module-qtquick-dialogs`, `qml6-module-qtquick-window`, `qml6-module-qtquick-layouts`, `qml6-module-qtcore`.